# How do I create a nested for each when running a azure cli command using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, foreach, azure-resource-group, azure-storage-account

I have the following command that grabs a list of storage accounts and run the following command against them:

```
foreach($storage in Get-Content .\storageaccount.txt) {
   Write-Host $storage
   az storage logging show --account-name $storage
}
```

If I want to run this command:

`az storage account management-policy show --account-name "StorageAccountName" --resource-group "RGName"`

1. How do I grab the Resource Group associated with that Storage Account and plug it into a variable?
2. How do I construct the for each loop to loop through the Storage Account and the Resource Groups?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Ok, so you will need to take some initiative here, look at the PowerShell Modules provided to see what you can come up with to pull it out.  I don't know how your data is stored or what you can query on, but it appears you can do wild card names, locations, and tags from the [PowerShell Module for Azure Storage Get-AzResourceGroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-5.2.0).  If that doesn't work, then try looking through the documentation for something that will work.

**Old Reply with Invalid code**

Is there a reason you don't want to use the [PowerShell module for Azure Storage][2]?

Using the module it would return an object (vs parsing text) and your code would be something like:

```
 foreach($Storage in Get-Content .\storageaccount.txt) {
    Write-Host $Storage
    $StorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $Storage #Requires more parameters

    Write-Host "Resource Group: $($StorageAccount.ResourceGroupName)"
}
```

Comment: Get-AzStorageAccount: 
Line |
   3 |      $StorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storage
     |                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.

Comment: Probably a bad example.  This may help you to get the name, but you have to figure out what you can query on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-5.2.0

Comment: I get the error above when using your suggestion ^

Comment: So if I'm trying to run this command: az storage account management-policy show --account-name "StorageAccountName" --resource-group "RGName".    How can I plug int the Resource Group name?